# Question about getting urls in Django

Tags: django, httpwebrequest, django-urls

I have this page `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/tom-brandy/`.

There is a link on the page to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/`.

How can I extract `tom-brandy` in my view that renders the `signup` page?

I was thinking of using `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` and using string manipulation to get it but it sounds like a wrong way to go about this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explicitly pass the user information to the signup link as a get parameter `/signup/?user=tom-brandy`

You could also use the session to set an arbitrary variable in the `user` pages and pull it in the signup page. That would probably be the cleanest and most transparent method.

```
('user/(?P<user>[\w-]+)/', 'my.user_view')

def user_view(request, user):
    request.session['last_visited_user_page'] = user
    # ...

def signup_view(request):
    last_visited_user_page = request.session.get('last_visited_user_page')
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression on your urls that extracts tom-brandy out of http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/tom-brandy and passes that as a first argument to your signup view

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpRequest.path_info` or `HttpRequest.path` as required.

The relevant documentation: [HttpRequest.path_info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)